# GNOME extensions are no longer working after activating Intel TearFree

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, tearing

I have a notebook with an Intel i3 and have screen-tearing. After consulting Arch Linux wiki on "Intel graphics" I found the recommendation to enable TearFree in Xorg:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"

   Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

After enabling and rebooting, most of my GNOME Shell extensions no longer work, e.g., app indicator, Workspace Indicator, etc.

I am not able to find any info online regarding this.

The system is a Ubuntu 18.04.03 one (all up to date).

Does someone know a solution to this?

Comment: What does this report, if anything..  `egrep -w  'SNA|TearFree'  /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Answer (score 0):

OK, interesting enough the problem does not appear today after testing again?!
I did the same thing today that I tried yesterday multiple times.

Hard to say what could have changed.

Thanks to doug for trying to help.